# Building QGIS source code on Windows 7 - Not working

Tags: qgis

As mentioned [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html#toc12) I've tried to build the QGIS on Windows 7.

There are two methods one using Visual Studio Express Edition installer and the second one using MinGW.

I've found both of them broken and don't know what to do next

**In building using [Visual Studio](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/d/7/cd7d4dfb-5290-4cc7-9f85-ab9e3c9af796/vc_web.exe)**
The link to visual studio actually installs the version 2010 but documentation assumes it version 2009. So "`set VS90COMNTOOLS=%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\`" path is not found.

Also I'm confused about the context of this line:

> If the path to bison and flex contains blanks, you need to use the
>   short name for the directory (i.e. C:\Program Files should be
>   rewritten to C:\Progra~n, where n is the number as shown in `dir /x
>   C:``).

**In Building using MinGW**  [4.2.1. MSYS](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win32/msys.zip) link is not found(404) but when I try to build step by step I find XDR 4.0 not found(404) in [this page](http://www.webalice.it/marco.pasetti/qgis+grass/BuildFromSource.html)

**So what's the way to build it?**
All I want is to change the title and startup photo of QGIS Desktop software.

Using another application I'm now able to change the title of running QGIS but don't know where to change the photo which shows "Loading plugins...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build instructions for Windows 7 are a tad long in the tooth, but they work for the most part. I did not try MinGW.

I immediately changed the VS90COMNTOOLS path to point to the Visual Studio 2010 directory and it seemed to work for me:

```
set VS90COMNTOOLS=%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
```

Regarding bison and flex configuration, I used the [latest version of CMake (3.3.1 as of now)](http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.3/cmake-3.3.1-win32-x86.exe) and didn't encounter any warnings/errors pertaining to bison or flex. Are you encountering any right now? If not, you should be able to proceed.

Comment: It is simply endless nightmare for me to build. Everytime I run cmake-gui it gets stuck in somewhere. Right now in QWTPOLAR_LIBRARY.

Comment: @user5858 Did you try enabling the WITH_INTERNAL_QWTPOLAR option in the entry list?

Comment: that did it, it's now generating the code. I'd publish a video about this.

Comment: I'm stuck in new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018563/unresolved-symbols-while-building-qgis