# ImportError: No module named PyQt4 when building QGIS

Tags: python-2.7, qgis

When building "ALL_BUILD" in Visual Studio 10 Express I'm getting this error

```
219>------ Rebuild All started: Project: pyconsole, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
219>  Building Custom Rule D:/QGIS/python/console/CMakeLists.txt
211>  qgsgeoreftoolmovepoint.cpp
219>  Traceback (most recent call last):
219>    File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py", line 31, in <module>
219>      from PyQt4 import QtCore
219>  ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

The code where error in pyuic.py has occurred looks like:

```
28 import sys
29 import optparse

31 from PyQt4 import QtCore
32 from PyQt4.uic.driver import Driver
```

But I can see QtCore.pyd file in C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4 folder.

Don't know why it's giving error.

Comment: Is that reproducible if you execute that `import` statement directly in the python ( _C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\python.exe_ ) console? Also, is there any _\_\_init\_\_.py(c)_ file in the _PyQt4_ folder?

Comment: Do you still have your CMake output available? What happens if you run CMake again with a new cache? I'm curious as to if it says `Found PyQt4 version: 4.XX.X`.

Comment: @David I had also installed Python 2.7 separately. Now I've it removed and trying to build again. I'll update you.

Comment: I'm getting error `C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python27.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2C0` and also unresolved external symbols QwtPlot ...

Comment: @user5858, that's new. But first, CMake properly picks up Python and PyQt now? Second, perhaps a reinstall using OSGeo4W might help?

Comment: @David same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018563/unresolved-symbols-while-building-qgis please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/93751/qgis-install?tab=general)

Answer (score -2):

I found solution for windows to ImportError: No module named PyQt4

- Python 2.7.11
- PyQt GPL 4.10.4
- MySQL

[image]